# Ruby code hash of array based of a cutoff

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of floating numbers and a certain cutoff:

```
myData = [1.3,1.5,1.7,1.7,16.7,18.4,19.2,19.5,19.6,20.2,20.8,58.4,60.7,
          61.2,61.2,116.4,121.2,122.7,123.2,123.2,138.5,149.5,149.5]
myBin = 5.3
```

I'd like to build a hash of arrays so that the difference by subtraction between the last element and the first element of the array is less or equal to myBin (5.3)

```
myHash = {
'hap_1' => [1.3,1.5,1.7],
'hap_2' => [16.8, 18.4,19.2,19.5,19.6,20.2,20.8],
'hap_3' => [58.4,60.7,61.2,61.2],
'hap_4' => [116.4,121.2],
'hap_5' => [122.7,123.2,123.2],
'hap_6' => [138.5],
'hap_7' => [149.5,149.5]}
```

Thank you so much in advance for your time and helpful assistance.
Cheers

Comment: Have you attempted a solution yourself?

Comment: You should use `snake_case` for variable names in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myData.drop(1).each_with_object([[myData.first]]) { |n,a|
  n - a.last.first <= myBin ? (a.last << n) : a << [n] }.
  each.with_index(1).with_object({}) { |(a,i),h| h["hap_#{i}"] = a }
  #=> {"hap_1"=>[1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7],
  #    "hap_2"=>[16.7, 18.4, 19.2, 19.5, 19.6, 20.2, 20.8],
  #    "hap_3"=>[58.4, 60.7, 61.2, 61.2],
  #    "hap_4"=>[116.4, 121.2],
  #    "hap_5"=>[122.7, 123.2, 123.2],
  #    "hap_6"=>[138.5],
  #    "hap_7"=>[149.5, 149.5]}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Enumerable#slice_before`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) can solve your problem:

```
first = myData[0]
myData.slice_before { |e| first = e if e - first > myBin }.to_a
#=> [[1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7],
#    [16.7, 18.4, 19.2, 19.5, 19.6, 20.2, 20.8],
#    [58.4, 60.7, 61.2, 61.2],
#    [116.4, 121.2],
#    [122.7, 123.2, 123.2],
#    [138.5],
#    [149.5, 149.5]]
```

Comment: Solves the core issue however note the OP wanted a hash. Unless you left it on purpose to leave the OP something to do:)

Comment: Lovely answer. As you are relying on `nil` being returned when the `if` clause is not true, it may be more clear to write `myData.slice_before { |n| n-first > myBin ? (first=n) : false }.to_a`. Two variants are `myData.slice_when { |_,n| n-first > myBin ? (first=n) : false }.to_a` and 
 `myData.chunk_while { |_,n| n-first <= myBin ? true : !(first=n) }.to_a`.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a customer enumerator that works like `chunk_while`, but compares each chunk's *first* element to the current one, i.e. `1.3` to `1.5`, then `1.3` to `1.7` and so on:

```
module Enumerable
  def chunk_while1
    return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
    each_with_object([]) do |elt, result|
      if result.last && yield(result.last.first, elt)
        result.last << elt
      else
        result << [elt]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
data = [
  1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7, 16.7, 18.4, 19.2, 19.5, 19.6, 20.2, 20.8, 58.4, 60.7,
  61.2, 61.2, 116.4, 121.2, 122.7, 123.2, 123.2, 138.5, 149.5, 149.5
]

result = data.chunk_while1 { |i, j| j - i <= 5.3 }
#=> [
#     [1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7],
#     [16.7, 18.4, 19.2, 19.5, 19.6, 20.2, 20.8],
#     [58.4, 60.7, 61.2, 61.2],
#     [116.4, 121.2],
#     [122.7, 123.2, 123.2],
#     [138.5],
#     [149.5, 149.5]
#   ]
```

The result can then be converted to a hash, e.g. via:

```
result.map.with_index(1) { |a, i| ["hap_#{i}", a] }.to_h
#=> {
#     "hap_1"=>[1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7],
#     "hap_2"=>[16.7, 18.4, 19.2, 19.5, 19.6, 20.2, 20.8],
#     "hap_3"=>[58.4, 60.7, 61.2, 61.2],
#     "hap_4"=>[116.4, 121.2],
#     "hap_5"=>[122.7, 123.2, 123.2],
#     "hap_6"=>[138.5],
#     "hap_7"=>[149.5, 149.5]
#   }
```